# Live traffic cam scraping

Tags: python, image, web, web-scraping

I would like to know what is the most elegant way to scrape live webcam (traffic) data, ideally using Python. The webcam feed is represented by an API, with each get request yielding a image of the currently available feed from the webcam. The feed in question has a 2/3 second delay and therefore there are ~ 30 images per minute that can be requested.

My current (trivial) solution simply queries the API in a loop (perhaps with a sleep timer) and then cleans up any duplicated images. However, this seems quite dirty and I was wondering if there is a cleaner/more elegant solution available.

In principal I would like the solution to (if at all possible) avoid:

- downloading duplicated images
- sleep timers
- looping

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid sleep timers in your code, you can write a process that is triggered by [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Cron will handle running your script at defined intervals, such as every 2 seconds (60s / 30 images per minute).

An example process might call the API using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/). Assuming an image is passed back, the following example code might work. If a JSON string is passed back then you will need to parse it and extract the image URL.

```
r = requests.get('https://traffic-cam-site.com/cam', auth=('user', 'pass'))

if r.status == 200:
    image = r.content
```

To avoid downloading duplicate images, you would need to know when a new image is present on the API. You will need to periodically check the cam site API for this purpose. Store a [hash](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/11/27/image-hashing-opencv-python/) of the collected images in a database (or text file), and send that with your request to the API. Then hash the image that is currently present on the cam site - if the hashes match, don't download the image to your server.

Alternatively, if the cam site API does [push notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API) then you may be notified when a new image is present.